# Set Visual Studio project Debug properties programmatically

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, programmatically-created

[Using Visual Studio Pro 2019]

I would like to be able to programmatically set the options on the Debug page of a C# project (using .NET Framework), without having to access the GUI. *I.e.* these parameters:

[image: Debug page of project properties]

Is there an API for this?

Comment: These options are just in the .csproj file. You just need to create/delete or modify the correct xml tags.

Comment: @Franck not necessarily - some (if not all) of the options reside in the .csproj.user file. This is of course a last-ditch option, to modify the XML files - I am hoping not to have to do that.

Comment: So why do you need to modify this by code ? It might help figure it out an alternative.

Comment: @Franck a client is specifically requesting this functionality. Odd I know, but hoping it can be done.

Comment: You can search here: [.NET API browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=visualstudiosdk-2019&term=debug). If you didn't find a proper API there, then there should be no such APIs.